# "Unable to start embedded Tomcat" exception when starting my grails application

Tags: tomcat, grails

When starting my java application I receive this exception:

```
2023-05-26 21:21:47,253 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader  - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 835848 ms
2023-05-26 21:21:48,665 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager  - Initialize failed.
2023-05-26 21:21:48,666 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  - Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'httpSessionServletListener': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionTimeoutListener' while setting bean property 'listener'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionTimeoutListener': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userHelperService' while setting bean property 'userHelperService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userHelperService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'org_grails_plugin_cache_GrailsCacheManagerAware__grailsCacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsCacheManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.ehcache.StateTransitionException: Cache 'reportCache' creation in EhcacheManager failed.
2023-05-26 21:21:48,721 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  - Stopping service [Tomcat]
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49323', transport: 'socket'
2023-05-26 21:22:28,211 [main] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext  - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2023-05-26 21:22:28,230 [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer  - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-05-26 21:22:28,246 [main] ERROR o.springframework.boot.SpringApplication  - Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at app.Application.main(Application.groovy:19)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
```

I don't have any local changes (I even did a git reset --hard) and nothing has changed, I start it as I usually do with intellij. Suddenly it start giving me this error. Not sure is related but before this it kept failing with `OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` multiple times because I did some big computations so I had to restart it multiple times so after 3 restarts it doesn't start any more. I've tried to Invalidate Caches and restart, reclone the project (same behavior), start the application from command line but same exception keeps appearing.
I am using grails 3.3.9.

I saw other posts related with "Unable to start embedded Tomcat" but the replies there were referring to bad changes you have locally so for some of them it help adding some annotations, or checking the application.groovy file but in my case I don't have any local changes and it used to start before this so no bad config.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all sorts of things, I managed to start the application by deleting everything I had between cache from ehcache-config.xml.